# get Composite Type into WSDL even though it is not in service interface

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have a simple DTO defined, with Datacontract and Datamember attributes, all of the datamembers are integers. I was returning a list of it which worked fine. But now I am compressing the list and returning as a byte array. Now that my service no longer returns the DTO as part of its interface, it does not generate the class in the service reference. I cant uncompress it as I have no type to work with on the client side.

I am using visual studio to generate the service reference.

All of the examples seem to be about exposing a known type where a class has another class as one of its properties. So they declare a type and then a known  type, or are using inheritance etc. I just want to declare the type.

I have tried many things including

```
<dataContractSerializer>
  <declaredTypes>
    <add type="PGF.Business.CustomerCropYearDTO, PGF_ExternalService">
    </add>
  </declaredTypes>
</dataContractSerializer>
```

Here is an abbreviated version of the class.

```
<DataContract()>
Public Class CustomerCropYearDTO

    <DataMember()> Public Property CustomerCropYearId As Integer
End Class
```

I am working in VB but a C# answer would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

hum.. If I am understanding well, you changed the DTO to include a binary and now you are trying to handle the compression during the object instantiation before the service invoke. Am I right?

The Gzip compression can be handled in message level. You could try to keep the data contract with the "real properties" (instead of the byte array) and create a custom binding with Gzip compression. There is a good WCF sample [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459) (navigate to "WCF/Extensibility/MessageEncoder/Compression/CS").

Comment: I changed the service interface from returning the DTO to returning a byte array. Now WCF does not "know" that the DTO is being returned to the client. So it does not generate it in the proxy.